# How to trigger a file download using R

Tags: html, r, web-crawler, rvest

I am trying to use R to trigger a file download on this site: http://www.regulomedb.org. Basically, an ID, e.g., rs33914668, is input in the form, click Submit. Then in the new page, click Download in the bottom left corner to trigger a file download.

I have tried rvest with the help from other posts.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pre_pg <- read_html("http://www.regulomedb.org")
POST(
  url = "http://www.regulomedb.org", 
  body = list(
    data = "rs33914668"
  ),
  encode =  "form"
  )
) -> res
pg <- content(res, as="parsed")
```

By checking pg, I think I am still on the first page, not the http://www.regulomedb.org/results. (I don't know how to check pg list other than reading it line by line). So, I cannot reach the download button. I cannot figure out why it cannot jump to the next page.

By learning from some other posts, I managed to download the file without using rvest.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)

session <- html_session("http://www.regulomedb.org")
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
filledform <- set_values(form, `data` = "rs33914668")

session2 <- submit_form(session, filledform)
form2 <- html_form(session2)[[1]]
filledform2 <- set_values(form2)

thesid <- filledform2[["fields"]][["sid"]]$value
theurl <- paste0('http://www.regulomedb.org/download/',thesid)
download.file(theurl,destfile="test.bed",method="libcurl")
```

In filledform2, I found the sid. Using www.regulomedb.org/download/:sid, I can download the file.

I am new to html or even R, and don't even know what sid is. Although I made it, I am not satisfied with the coding. So, I hope some experienced users can provide better, alternative solutions, or improve my current solution. Also, what is wrong with the POST/rvest method?

Comment: Looking at the code on the page it appears that a simple POST should work if you match the value names expected with the names in your list. Have you examined the examples? The form section reads: `<form action="/results" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
           <textarea id="input_text" name="data" rows="12">
</textarea>          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form></div>`

Comment: The element's name is data. After POST, the elements of the webpage indicate that it is still the first page. I have tried different examples but the issue persists. I saw someone use add_header and wonder if it is the reason for the problem.

Comment: The `sid` is a session ID (and was sent to your browser as a cookie). Look at the entire session result with `str(session2)`. It's showing the ways to access the next page that was presented to the user when the `textarea` was filled it with `rs33914668` and the submit button was pressed. It had many list elements, one of which was `$ url     : chr "http://www.regulomedb.org/results"`. I got the POST to work by  adding `data=c(submit="submit")` to the submit_form arguments. You will now need to look at that new webpage and decide which of the many possible actions you want to emulate in code.

Answer (score 2):

```
url<-"http://www.regulomedb.org/"
library(rvest)
page<-html_session(url)

download_page<-rvest:::request_POST(page,url="http://www.regulomedb.org/results",
                                    body=list("data"="rs33914668"),
                                    encode = 'form')

#This is a unique id on generated based on your query
sid<-html_nodes(download_page,css='#download > input[type="hidden"]:nth-child(8)') %>% html_attr('value')

#This is a UNIX time
download_token<-as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))

download_page1<-rvest:::request_POST(download_page,url="http://www.regulomedb.org/download",
                                    body=list("format"="bed",
                                              "sid"=sid,
                                              "download_token_value_id"=download_token ),
                                    encode = 'form')
writeBin(download_page1$response$content, "regulomedb_result.bed")
```

Comment: Upvoted with a "but ...". This looks like a potentially useful response but it is only code. Code-only answers are deprecated on SO so I'm suggesting that you explain issues such as how you chose your arguments and why you decided to use the R Sys.time-value as your "download_token".

Comment: Apologies. I copied and pasted the code in vain.
When I analyzed the requests there was a download token which resembled a UNIX time, I converted that to normal time and confirmed that it was a UNIX time (I think it doesn't matter whatever time is sent in that field 'download_token'

Comment: Thanks a lot! You solved the problem and gave me another solution which I can learn from. Great job!